# T-SQL Filter XML Variable

Tags: sql, xml

I was wondering which one of the following two was the better way of filtering on a column in my xml variable.

```
INSERT INTO [Tracking].[Team]([Name], [Description], [Begin_Dt], [End_Dt], [Update_Dt])
SELECT 
        x.[Team].value('Name', 'varchar(100)') AS [Name],
        x.[Team].value('Description', 'varchar(250)') AS [Description],
        x.[Team].value('Begin_Dt', 'datetime') AS [Begin_Dt],
        x.[Team].value('End_Dt', 'datetime') AS [End_Dt],
        getdate() as [Update_Dt]
FROM @xml.nodes('/Team') x([Team])
WHERE x.[Team].value('Team_Ref_ID', 'int') = 0


INSERT INTO [Tracking].[Team]([Name], [Description], [Begin_Dt], [End_Dt], [Update_Dt])
SELECT 
        x.[Team].value('Name', 'varchar(100)') AS [Name],
        x.[Team].value('Description', 'varchar(250)') AS [Description],
        x.[Team].value('Begin_Dt', 'datetime') AS [Begin_Dt],
        x.[Team].value('End_Dt', 'datetime') AS [End_Dt],
        getdate() as [Update_Dt]
FROM @xml.nodes('/Team') x([Team])
WHERE x.[Team].exist('Team_Ref_ID[. = 0]') = 1
```

Notice the WHERE clause, one uses exist, the other uses value, or is there a third method that's more effective ?

Thanks,
Raul

Comment: Assuming that "better" means "performs better", have you tried looking at the query plans for both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what i found to be better was this

```
INSERT INTO [Tracking].[Team]([Name], [Description], [Begin_Dt], [End_Dt], [Update_Dt])
SELECT 
        x.[Team].value('Name', 'varchar(100)') AS [Name],
        x.[Team].value('Description', 'varchar(250)') AS [Description],
        x.[Team].value('Begin_Dt', 'datetime') AS [Begin_Dt],
        x.[Team].value('End_Dt', 'datetime') AS [End_Dt],
        getdate() as [Update_Dt]
FROM @xml.nodes('/Team[Team_Ref_Id = 0]') x([Team])
```

It filters out the nodes in the xml parser instead of having to filter them out in the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

For querying an @xml variable the best improvement you can do is to have it be of type with an XML schema, see [Typed XML Compared to Untyped XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184277.aspx). This will benefit the XPath expressions in your query (the `.nodes('/Team')`, the various `.value` and the `.exists` operators). But there will be an upfront cost in validating the schema when the variable is assigned.

The other typical XML performance improvement is XML indexes, but unfortunately they cannot be applied to variables so the point is mute in regard to your problem.

As to your particular minutia question (whether the  `.value('Team_Ref_ID')` is faster than `.exists('Team_Ref_ID[. = 0]')`) I *think* the former is faster, but I have no evidence and I may well be wrong.